# How to define union generic types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

we can use:

```
type stringNumber = string | number;
```

But what about:

```
type MapSet<T> = Map<T> | Set<T>;
```

Is it possible in some way?

P.S. this is needed to reduce interface definitions length.

**UPDATE:**

```
type MapSet<T> = Map<T> | Set<T>;
```

such definition is correct in typeScript 1.6 and you can use it today, as Ryan wrote below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type aliases with generic type parameters are in TypeScript 1.6.

You can wait for that version to come out, or install the TypeScript nightly build (`npm install typescript@next`)

Comment: Cool, and there are list of features in current nightly?

Answer (score 0):

That's a an interesting question. The following did compile but having to wrap each value is certainly not optimal.

```
interface MapSet<T> {
  wrapper: Map<T> | Set<T>;
}
```